# C++ Iterate Map Dynamically

Tags: c++

New to C++. I have tables in a database formatted like this.

```
      date  |  col1  |  col2  |  col3
________________________________________
01-01-2000  | 10.00  | 11.00  | 12.00
01-02-2000  | 20.00  | 21.00  | 22.00
       ...  |   ...  |   ...  |  ...
```

I want to get 1 row from each table and push it into a map array.

```
std::map<string, double> row_data;

res = mysql_store_result(conn)
while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
    for (unsigned int x= 0; x < columns.size(); x++)   // FOR EACH COLUMN
    {
        row_data[itemlist[j]] = row[x] // WRONG
```

After iterating I want to have a multidimensional array such that:

```
array = [[row_data], [row_data], [row_data], ...] // FOR table1, table2, table3 ...
```

And `row_data` output would be:

```
col1 10.00
col2 11.00
col3 12.00
```

Sending column data to `row_data` doesn't work dynamically. How can I iterate and fill the map?

Comment: Fetch records from table; Use for-loop to fill the map. You are complicating the code.

Comment: Yes but what is the proper way to set variables in the array? `row_data[itemlist[j]] = row[x]`

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: I will edit the above code.

Comment: A) Why C-style `for` instead of [range-based `for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)? B) Why aren't you using the [C++ Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/) instead of the rudimentary and very low-level C driver?

Comment: A) I didn't know the difference B) I am using the C++ Connector for MySQL, that portion of it isn't a problem I think

Comment: row_data is of type `std::map<string, double>`. what about the date column?

Comment: date column is a string